# how to enable minor-modes for scratch buffer

Tags: emacs

I want to get rainbow-delimiters enabled for .el files as well as the scratch buffer. The [installation page](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Installation) says that the 
`(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)` is disabled. is there a `scratch-buffer-mode-hook` that I can add on to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*scratch*` buffer uses `lisp-interaction-mode`, which is based upon `emacs-lisp-mode`. So simply adding adding to `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` will enable the mode for both `.el` files and the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```